# Qt поэлементный скролл

Tags: c++, qt

Вопрос такой, есть QScrollArea с некоторым количеством кнопок на ней. Для области установлен скролл через `QScroller::grabGesture(viewport(), QScroller::TouchGesture);`
Как сделать, чтобы скролл заканчивался таким образом, чтобы виджет был четко середине области.
Буду благодарен за любую инфу, т.к. даже не знаю как правильно называется такой тип скролла.

[image: скролл_1]